# Android TV apk: It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions

Tags: android, google-play, android-tv

I developed an app a while ago for phones and tablets. A few weeks ago i also create a different APK for Android TV's and uploaded it as beta. The TV app was rejected for some reasons (not relevant here).

A few days ago I created a single APK for both phone and TV, and got the following error while trying to upload it in google play:

```
- It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 33 (target SDK 23) to version 35 (target SDK 22).
- A device with API levels in range 21+ is eligible to receive version 13, which is optimized for higher API levels, but actually receives version 15 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Release track containing any of [BETA] and Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and Features containing all of [android.hardware.MICROPHONE, android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.software.LEANBACK].
 - A device upgrading from API levels in range 9-20 to API levels in range 21+ would become eligible to receive version 33, which is optimized for higher API levels, but would actually receive version 35 because it has a higher version code. This would occur when 
Release track containing any of [BETA] and Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.MICROPHONE, android.hardware.screen.LANDSCAPE, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT, android.software.LEANBACK].
- Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
```

I understood that it was a problem that my tv APK was using targetSDK = 23, while the new APK was using targetSDK = 22.

So now i **deactivated the beta APK** for TV's, but is still get the following errors:

```
It is forbidden to downgrade devices which previously used M permissions (target SDK 23 and above) to APKs which use old style permissions (target SDK 22 and below). This occurs in the change from version 33 (target SDK 23) to version 35 (target SDK 22).
Some devices are eligible to run multiple APKs. In such a scenario, the device will receive the APK with the higher version code.
```

Comment: Even if you deactivate the APK on Google Play that doesn't remove that version of the app from any of the devices that it's been installed on. If I understand you correctly, the first beta was rejected before anyone had a chance to download it. You might want to contact the Google Player support and explain the situation to them.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#perm-request):

> On all versions of Android, your app needs to declare both the normal and the dangerous permissions it needs in its app manifest. However, the **effect of that declaration is different depending on the system version and your app's target SDK level**:

You should update your new build if you'll use `targetSdkVersion 23`:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```